# How to set paper size of B4 paper (Format not found in PrintSetup) in Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

I understand setting paper size of JIS size B4 paper in Apache POI.
PrintSetup class has JIS size B4 property.( https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html ) But ISO size B4 not listed.

I want to set paper size of ISO size B4 paper in Apache POI.

how do that?

---

Reference
https://mojoprint.jp/guide/international-paper-sizes.php

I'm sorry for the confusion,
I think the B4 JIS standard size in PrintSetup is actually ISO standard B4 size. In the question, I'm using the Javadoc representation of the Apache POI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI's paper sizes, for example [PrintSetup.B4_PAPERSIZE](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/constant-values.html#org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PrintSetup.B4_PAPERSIZE) = 12, corresponds to [XlPaperSize enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpapersize) where you find:

> ```
> Name            Value      Description
> xlPaperB4       12         B4 (250 mm x 354 mm)
> ```

And that is exactly ISO 216 B4 size.

JIS size of B4 would be 257 mm × 364 mm. But that is not available in Excel. So the text in Apache POI's javadoc is wrong.